# Check if user is on backend page

Tags: plugins

i trying to run a script only on packed page... but i cant find the right hook

here is my script

```
function posts_for_current_author($query) {
    global $current_user;
    if($current_user->data->wp_user_level < 9) {
        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author',  $user_ID);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `is_admin();` in your `if` query , http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin